# In-App Billing isBillingSupported - returns what and functions how?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

The question is based around the Google In-App Billing service for Android. Specifically the function `isBillingSupported`.

```
int result = mBillingService.isBillingSupported(3, mOwner.getPackageName(), "inapp")
```

Firstly, what does this function return? The docs are incredibly secretive on this:

> RESULT_OK(0) on success, corresponding result code on failures

The [only codes I found](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html) seem unrelated to the question of billing being supported. All that seems concrete, is that 0 is successful. What errors can there be?

Secondly, what does this function check for to know whether billing is supported? I have a phone that is completely capable of In-App billing, and this function does indeed return "true" when I am connected to a reasonable internet source, such as WiFi. However, if my connection is less stable, it will not return "true". So I assume that it checks for a good connection. What else does it check for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The other response codes are:-

- RESULT_OK = 0 - success
- RESULT_USER_CANCELED = 1 - user pressed back or canceled a dialog
- RESULT_BILLING_UNAVAILABLE = 3 - this billing API version is not supported for the type requested
- RESULT_ITEM_UNAVAILABLE = 4 - requested SKU is not available for purchase
- RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR = 5 - invalid arguments provided to the API
- RESULT_ERROR = 6 - Fatal error during the API action
- RESULT_ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED = 7 - Failure to purchase since item is already owned
- RESULT_ITEM_NOT_OWNED = 8 - Failure to consume since item is not owned

Comment: I have read those before, but I thought they were for transactions. Are they for the entire API? Already owned makes no sense when querying whether billing is possible. Do you know what the billing supported function checks for?

Comment: yes they are for the entire API. this function actually checks whether the item your are buying using in app purchase supports in-app billing or not. Here support means that whether item is available for purchase or not. So the codes written in previous answer are for that scenarios i.e if user already owned that item, item SKU is not available or incorrect etc.

Answer (score -3):

```
public int isBillingSupported(int apiVersion, java.lang.String packageName, java.lang.String type) throws android.os.RemoteException;

/**
     * Provides details of a list of SKUs
     * Given a list of SKUs of a valid type in the skusBundle, this returns a bundle
     * with a list JSON strings containing the productId, price, title and description.
     * This API can be called with a maximum of 20 SKUs.
     * @param apiVersion billing API version that the Third-party is using
     * @param packageName the package name of the calling app
     * @param skusBundle bundle containing a StringArrayList of SKUs with key "ITEM_ID_LIST"
     * @return Bundle containing the following key-value pairs
     *         "RESPONSE_CODE" with int value, RESULT_OK(0) if success, other response codes on
     *              failure as listed above.
     *         "DETAILS_LIST" with a StringArrayList containing purchase information
     *              in JSON format similar to:
     *              '{ "productId" : "exampleSku", "type" : "inapp", "price" : "$5.00",
     *                 "title : "Example Title", "description" : "This is an example description" }'
     */
```

Comment: It cannot only check the services version, because it returns differently depending on whether I have WiFi on or 3G or 3G (but with really bad reception). And I know of 0 for the successful return code, but what else is there?

Comment: That's the wrong comment (corresponding to getSkuDetails).